# Trigger a function when slide is visible then destroy it once it's finished, then repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slick.js

That was probably the worst title above, but I'll try and explain my self a little better here.

At the moment I have a simple fading carousel which is powered by slick and that's working fine. It show's one slide, then fades to the next slide.

As well as that, I have a simple type writer [plugin](http://macarthur.me/typeit/docs/) which types out the content within the slide.

The problem I'm facing is that when I trigger the typewriter function it triggers all of the content on all other carousel slides to start typewriting all at once when really I would like it to typewrite out the visible slide and then trigger again when the next slide is visible.

I've tried quite a few things but haven't had much luck. Do I have to destroy the typewriter function when it's done and then load it again on slide? If anyone could shed some light on it I'd be really appreciative.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q1qznouw/688/)

```
$(function () {
  $('#dashboard').slick({
    fade : true,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 3000,
    arrows: false,
    pauseOnHover: false
  });
  $('.panel').typeIt({});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to use the [typeit](https://github.com/alexmacarthur/typeit) efffect for each visible slide in the [slick carousel](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick) you can use the **beforeChange** event.

Using the last version of slick, the example is:

```js
$('#dashboard').slick({
  fade : true,
  autoplay: true,
  autoplaySpeed: 3000,
  arrows: false,
  pauseOnHover: false
});

$('.panel').eq(0).typeIt({loop: true}); // typeit on the first ele
$('#dashboard').on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
  //
  // typeit the current slide if not yet initialized
  //
  // if ($('.panel').eq(nextSlide).find('.ti-placeholder').length == 0)
  // 
  // or, you may test:
  //
  if ($('.panel').eq(nextSlide).tiSettings().is('.panel') == false) {
    $('.panel').eq(nextSlide).typeIt({loop: true});
  }
});
```

```css
#nav {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.panel {
  border: 10px solid #333;
  background: #ccc;
  height:200px;
  margin: 10px;
  font-size: 72px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.6.0/slick.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.6.0/slick.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typeit/4.3.0/typeit.min.js"></script>

<div id="dashboard">
    <div class="panel">This is a test 1</div>
    <div class="panel">This is a test 2</div>
    <div class="panel">This is a test 3</div>
    <div class="panel">This is a test 4</div>
    <div class="panel">This is a test 5</div>
    <div class="panel">This is a test 6</div>
    <div class="panel">This is a test 7</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are a god! Thanks so much. I knew it would be something simple like that!

Comment: I have noticed that once it's cycled around all the slides it doesn't retrigger. Do you know why that would be?

Comment: @FrazerFindlater Snippet updated. The problem was: not re-initialize typeIt and set "loop: true" in order to typeIt forever. Let me know if it works. Thanks

Comment: Hmm, it seems as though loop just types it and then erases it and then types it again. Ideally it would just type it out and leave it there. Really appreciate the help! @gaetanoM

Comment: @FrazerFindlater  Thanks so much for sharing